# Facebook SDK PHP session sent does not match with the one received

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-php-sdk

I have basically copied the code that the Facebook API suggested, but while logging in, it returns the following error:

> Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation
>   failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.

**login.php (relevant part)**

```
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '***',
    'app_secret' => '***',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes']; // Optional permissions
var_dump($_SESSION, TRUE);
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/callback.php', $permissions);
```

I found that when I `var_dump($_SESSION)` (or `print_r`), login is successful, because the correct session state is sent.

I don't know why `var_dump` solves the problem though. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Likely the usual problem of correctly passing on the session id to the next script. How is the user getting to the login URL, are you automatically redirecting them to there from within your PHP script? Redirects often cause problems with browsers accepting cookies. Try and make that a link that the user explicitly needs to click to be taken to login.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out it must be something with cookies/session because it works fine in other browsers, but doesn't work in Chrome :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really strange, but turns out it's a webkit bug, and by adding `favicon` to the site, it works. -.-"

Comment: AWESOME!!! i was never gonna figure this out if it was'nt for your answer... that damn FAVICON... webkit browser call the page another time in the background because it tried to locate the icon, and it wa not there, using .htaccess to redirect to main page, that caused the fb-login-url loading twice with the old page load showing to the user....